# UK visa. Where to get biometrics in USA

Tags: visas, uk

Where can I get biometrics for UK passport in USA? Can't find a good answer anywhere. Last information I saw said ACS centers were not doing biometrics for UK visas.

Comment: There is nothing on the [UK Government site](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) or the [USCIS ASC site](https://egov.uscis.gov/office-locator/#/asc) that suggests that AScs aren't now providing biometric services.  Call your nearest ASC and ask them. If you do, please come back and answer your question for the benefit of others.

Comment: i called  the asc phone number they said the were doing biometrics the web address is www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/vacs. I logged on the site worked.

Comment: That was almost a year ago and lasted for about a week and a half.